# Unistall module without removing table Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am creating a module in drupal 7 where a table should be created during installation. I do not want the table will be deleted when the module is uninstalled. After doing some research, I have found couple of functions, i.e. `hook_install` and `drupal_install_schema`. But I do not understand how to use them as table will be created during installation but no deletion during uninstall module.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 7 uses hook_uninstall to trigger functions when a module is uninstalled, unless you tell Drupal to remove the tables with hook_install the they will remain intact.

```
[https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_uninstall/7.x][1]
```